# SelectableText hinttext is black

Tags: flutter

[image: screenshot] as displayed, i dont know which theme it is, but my hint text of SelectableText is black, i still can select it just can not see it, plz help to let me know, which option/color I can readjust, thanks!

```
SelectableText(
        element.name,
        cursorColor:Colors.green,
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        style: chatStyle(textColor: Colors.black),
      ),

 ThemeData(
        textSelectionTheme: const TextSelectionThemeData(
          cursorColor: Colors.yellow,
          selectionColor: Colors.green,
          selectionHandleColor: Colors.pink,
        ),
        textSelectionColor: Colors.yellow,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
        hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          color: Colors.black,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        cardColor: Colors.black,
        primaryColor: Colors.green,
        textTheme: TextTheme(

          headline5: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          caption: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
              fontSize: 14,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
          subtitle1: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          bodyText2: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including  `tooltipTheme`

```dart
data: ThemeData(
  tooltipTheme: TooltipThemeData(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.green
    )
  ),
```

Comment: Hi Yeasin thank you for your help, do you know which theme the tool text is (like Copy and Select All from SelectableText ) I tried textstyle from TooltipThemeData, but it is not correct